# Push view controller from app delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Bascially, I'm using push notifications and I'm receiving custom JSON payloads with an alert string and a channel string. The channel will tell my app which view to load when the notification is opened.

Only problem is, this is just theory...

I don't know what my options are for handling the pushing of the view when the notification is opened.

Can I do it from my app delegate at the same time my JSON is read?

Otherwise, what can I do?

That is the only issue, everything else is sorted, I just need to handle the view loading depending on the channel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you dont know the name of viewcontroller when loading in AppDelegate, right?

Comment: when the app is opened from a notification, i read the JSON data and get the channel name in didReceiveRemoteNotification, so at this point, yes, I know what view I want to push

Answer (score 0):

Then use following Code to load you view Controller with anonymous name of ViewController

Step 1: Create ViewController with Anonymous name from JSON

```
UIViewController* object = (UIViewController*)[[NSClassFromString(@"ViewController") alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerNibName" bundle:nil];
```

Step 2: Create Navigation Controller with ViewController

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:object];
```

Step 3 :Add Navigation Controller to Window

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Comment: its not object of it, but you can load any viewController without knowing which one to load, just write this three lines in app delegate and pass proper view controller name in string

Comment: Property navController not found on object of type AppDelegate

Comment: its not property of AppDelegate its individual object of Type UINavigationController